# Jagged/bad quality resolution after attaching second monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, scaling

I have a 2560 x 1440, 144 Hz monitor and a 3840 x 2160, 144 Hz monitor. I use a Geforce RTX 4070 TI.
The monitor with the lower resolution used to provide good quality when it was combined with a full HD monitor running at 60 Hz, after I found the appropriate set-up for cleartype text and scaling.
Now since I combined it with the 4k monitor, the 4k monitor looks great, whereas everything on the 3840x2160 monitor looks bad, especially with jagged text, but also low res logos (see screenshots - I am not sure of the problems are shown the same way on other monitors but it seems that way).

I tried to change clear type and scaling settings in Windows, but nothing really helps.
Can someone guide me into the right direction of dealing with this?

[image: bad monitor]

[image: bad monitor]

[image: good monitor]